# Working with window 8, Skype app, and Wamp

Tags: php, windows, apache, skype

I was having problem connecting my Wamp with window 8 while skype app was turned on. Does anyone know how to stop skype app on window 8 from using port 80?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, I had to take the following steps.

1. Click on the WAMP icon
2. Select Apache
3. Click on HTTPD.Conf
4. Search for "Listen"

Change

Listen 80

To

Listen 81

1. Save the document
2. Restart wamp
3. on the browser, type 
     `http://localhost:81/php_file.php`

Make sure you put the colon andn the 81 in order to view your request.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to skype > Tools > Option 
then from option >Advance then uncheck the checkbox "use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections"

Comment: How do you check that on window 8?

Comment: open your skype first then on your skype screen press alt + T then alt + O then click the advance tab then choose connection  =)